# How to call a simple Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a C# file named Service1.cs containing the following:

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{ 
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static String testMethod()
    {
       return "Hello";
    }
}
```

I put this snippet of code in my helloworld.html file:

```
<WebService Language="c#" Codebehind="Service1.cs"
    Class="Service1.Service1">
```

My directory is up at http://localhost:8000/, with a link to helloworld.html and a link to download Service1.cs

to what url must I go to to access the string returned by my testMethod()?

I've tried http://localhost:8000/helloworld/testmethod, http://localhost:8000/helloworld/Service1/testmethod,
but I can't figure out how to get to the string value returned from the web service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the code in your project / application where you are consuming the webservice meaning `Service1` you need to create an instance of the web service that you are consuming in order to call the webservice `testMethod()` do a simple google search on C# WebService Tutorial plenty of good examples are online as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can right click the **Project -> References**  and click **Add Service references** and paste the url,

[image]

Create a client like this and call method:

```
myService.Service1Client client = new myService.Service1Client();
var result = client.testMethod();
```

Comment: In which file do I write the client code?  Is it possible to access the string result simply by visiting the url?

Comment: you can write it in any app , winform .cs file or any asp .net cs file

Comment: is it possible to make an AJAX call to the service like so? $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/testMethod'
}).success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject);

Comment: Yes possible , but  you need to make the web service rest accessible https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AhmedMabrouckRoCa.ASPNETSOAPToRESTfulConverter